# Select and change style to a specific th or td

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS. The problem that I'm facing is change font in a specific th or td line. I'll try to explain in the code.

How to use CSS to choose the specific table cell to change style without JavaScript then use an attribute to put the style.

The code:

```html
<style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 3px solid white;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    th, td {
      padding:10px;
    }
</style>
<body style="color:white;background-color:black">
<html>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
        <th>dummy</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dummy</td>

<!--Part need to change style from this line--><td>dummy</td>

        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td>
        <td>dummy</td><!--to this line-->
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The comment part is to select the specific td then end select at the last comment.

I already used the tbody tag, but it doesn't work. Span and div tag don't work either.

How can I change the style from that part or need any tag?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could reduce the code. Usually it is recommended to provide a minimal (!), reproducible example. While your code is not huge, it is unnecessary to provide multiple <td>s. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I will provide an edit.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What prevents you from just adding a class-name, or data-attribute, to the cells you wish to highlight? Further, what have you attempted before you chose to ask a question here? We don't expect your attempts to be perfect, but we *do* expect you to make a credible attempt.

Comment: Your code as posted is broken HTML `<body style="color:white;background-color:black">
<html>`

Comment: You might simply apply a class to the elements i.e. `class="my-styled-thing"` (Consider giving it a good name like `odd-row` or some such which shows intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, this helps. Use `nth-child` and learn how to use it as selector.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) {background:yellow; font-family: 'comic sans ms'}
tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(3) {background:pink; font-family: 'comic sans ms'}
tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(4) {background:blue; font-family: 'times new roman'}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <td>dummy</td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <!--Part need to change style from this line-->
    <td>dummy</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <td>dummy</td>
    <!--to this line-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr:last-child td:not(:first-child)` selector to target the table cells (except the first one) in the last row:

```css
tr:last-child td:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: #ff07;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

body {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
    <th>dum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
    <td>dum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>dum</td>
    <!--Part need to change style from this line-->
   <td>dum 1</td>
    <td>dum 2</td>
    <td>dum 3</td>
    <td>dum 4</td>
    <td>dum 5</td>
    <td>dum 6</td>
    <td>dum 7</td>
   <!--to this line-->
  </tr>
</table>
```